# User input from textfield

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a class Course with properties such as setting a var to a string/int of user input from a textField. How would I implement this in Swift? I was thinking it would be something along the lines of

```
class Course { 
    let x = self.textFieldname.text! 
}
```

But I wind up with an error saying

> Instance member can not be used on type ViewController

Answer (score 0):

You would need to setup a `IBoutlet` for the textfield from your user interface file most commonly a `.storyboard` that would let a user input text and then you would be able to save that to variable. Most likely you would want a `IBAction` hooked up to a button so that they could say "Enter" or what ever you will. That way when the user hits the button you can capture the value of the textfield. If you have a  more specific question that would make it easier to direct you better.

Answer (score 0):

Your class will be handled by compiler before you get your input from TextField. I actually did not completely understand what kind of use-case you have planned for it. 
But probably what you want to do is create your Course class with empty or nil x variable(not constant, so you should use var.) and create an instance of Course class with a constructor when you read input from TextField or create your Course instance somewhere else and set x value later when you read input.

If you want further help, you should add more detailed information, and code from your work.